# How to add title in JPGraph from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, jpgraph

I generate chart using jpgraph. I succesfully get data for the plot from database and i want the title also take from database. i already use this script

```
$sql = $this->db->select("title from table")->get()->first_row();
$title = $sql->title;
$graph->title->Set($title);
```

But that not work. can anyone solve this issue? thank you

Comment: did u checked the answer?

Comment: yes but it is also no work

Comment: chk the result `echo $title;exit;` chk r u getting title or not before this line `$graph->title->Set($title);`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function first_row() on array

Comment: I check the results of sript in my question, the result is correct but can not be included in the chart title

Comment: $this->db->select('title');
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

it seems that you're using the wrong syntax for CodeIgniter query.

Answer (score 0):

This will help to get first_row along with field:

```
$this->db->select('title');  // your column
$this->db->from('table');   // your table
$result = $this->db->get()->result(); // get result
$title = $result->first_row()->title; // get ist row using first_row with your field name
$graph->title->Set($title); // as you are using for graph
```

*Also note that, in CI function `row()` also return the ist row of your query in object form.*

From the manual:

> You can walk forward/backwards/first/last through your results using
>   these variations:

```
$row = $query->first_row()
$row = $query->last_row()
$row = $query->next_row()
$row = $query->previous_row()
```

*Or if you want to print result in array instead of object than you can use a word 'array' as param, like:*

```
$query->first_row(‘array’)
```

*You can also follow the CI manual for better understanding: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html*